# How can I stream JSON from a file?

Tags: json, perl, stream

I will have a possibly very large JSON file and I want to stream from it instead of load it all into memory.  Based on the following statement (I added the emphasis) from [`JSON::XS`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON-XS/XS.pm#INCREMENTAL_PARSING), I believe it won't suit my needs.  Is there a Perl 5 JSON module that will stream the results from the disk?

> In some cases, there is the need for incremental parsing of JSON texts. While this module **always has to keep both JSON text and resulting Perl data structure in memory at one time**, it does allow you to parse a JSON stream incrementally. It does so by accumulating text until it has a full JSON object, which it then can decode. This process is similar to using decode_prefix to see if a full JSON object is available, but is much more efficient (and can be implemented with a minimum of method calls).

To clarify, the JSON will contain an array of objects.  I want to read one object at a time from the file.

Comment: I guess you've [searched](https://metacpan.org/search?q=json+stream)... are you looking for someone to vouch for a module? My rudimentary searches bring up [`JSON::Streaming::Reader`](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON::Streaming::Reader) and [`JSON::SL`](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON::SL) as potential candidates, but have no idea if they are suitable for your needs.

Comment: @Zaid I was just looking at the JSON modules, I didn't think to include stream in the name (I assumed, mistakenly it seems, that the top dogs would have this functionality).

Comment: Have a look at NDJSON. Newline Delimited JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [JSON::Streaming::Reader](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3A%3AStreaming%3A%3AReader) which shows up as first while searching for 'JSON Stream' on search.cpan.org?

Alternatively [JSON::SL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3A%3ASL) found by searching for 'JSON SAX' - not quite as obvious search terms, but what you describe sounds like a SAX parsers for XML.

Comment: I am reading the docs to JSON::SL right now, I will look at JSON::Streaming::Reader next.

Comment: As the author of JSON::SL, it offers both a pull-like interface (as featured in the example below) and an actual SAX-like interface (called `Tuba`). They are different, and the drawbacks of the SAX-style interface are visible (complex and slow..)

Answer (score 13):

In terms of ease of use and speed, [`JSON::SL`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3A%3ASL) seems to be the winner:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::SL;

my $p = JSON::SL->new;

#look for everthing past the first level (i.e. everything in the array)
$p->set_jsonpointer(["/^"]);

local $/ = \5; #read only 5 bytes at a time
while (my $buf = <DATA>) {
    $p->feed($buf); #parse what you can
    #fetch anything that completed the parse and matches the JSON Pointer
    while (my $obj = $p->fetch) {
        print "$obj->{Value}{n}: $obj->{Value}{s}\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
[
    { "n": 0, "s": "zero" },
    { "n": 1, "s": "one"  },
    { "n": 2, "s": "two"  }
]
```

[`JSON::Streaming::Reader`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3A%3AStreaming%3A%3AReader) was okay, but it is slower and suffers from too verbose an interface (all of these coderefs are required even though many do nothing):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::Streaming::Reader;

my $p = JSON::Streaming::Reader->for_stream(\*DATA);

my $obj;
my $attr;
$p->process_tokens(
    start_array    => sub {}, #who cares?
    end_array      => sub {}, #who cares?
    end_property   => sub {}, #who cares?
    start_object   => sub { $obj = {}; },     #clear the current object
    start_property => sub { $attr = shift; }, #get the name of the attribute
    #add the value of the attribute to the object
    add_string     => sub { $obj->{$attr} = shift; },
    add_number     => sub { $obj->{$attr} = shift; },
    #object has finished parsing, it can be used now
    end_object     => sub { print "$obj->{n}: $obj->{s}\n"; },
);

__DATA__
[
    { "n": 0, "s": "zero" },
    { "n": 1, "s": "one"  },
    { "n": 2, "s": "two"  }
]
```

To parse 1,000 records it took `JSON::SL` .2 seconds and `JSON::Streaming::Reader` 3.6 seconds (note, `JSON::SL` was being fed 4k at a time, I had no control over JSON::Streaming::Reader's buffer size).

Answer (score 2):

> It does so by accumulating text until it has a full JSON object, which it then can decode.

This is what screws your over. A JSON document **is** one object.

You need to define more clearly what you want from incremental parsing. Are you looking for one element of a large mapping? What are you trying to do with the information you read out/write?

---

I don't know any library that will incrementally parse JSON data by reading one element out of an array at once. However this is quite simple to implement yourself using a finite state automaton (basically your file has the format `\s*\[\s*([^,]+,)*([^,]+)?\s*\]\s*` except that you need to parse commas in strings correctly.)

Comment: I updated the question, the JSON is an array of objects and I want one object at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to skip first right braket `[` and then the commas `,` :

```
$json->incr_text =~ s/^ \s* \[ //x;
...
$json->incr_text =~ s/^ \s* , //x;
...
$json->incr_text =~ s/^ \s* \] //x;
```

like in the third example :
http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON-XS/XS.pm#EXAMPLES

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, the docs seem to say that it still keeps stuff in memory (i.e. there is no flush like `XML::Twig` has).

Comment: Actually, the fourth example seems to do what you want

Comment: It appears so, but it looks crufty as hell.  There are apparently other specialized modules on CPAN that may be able to hide that cruft from me.  I am looking at them now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over how you're generating your JSON, then I suggest turning pretty formatting off and printing one object per line.  This makes parsing simple, like so:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON::Parse 'json_to_perl';
use JSON;
use JSON::SL;
my $json_sl = JSON::SL->new();
use JSON::XS;
my $json_xs = JSON::XS->new();
$json_xs = $json_xs->pretty(0);
#$json_xs = $json_xs->utf8(1);
#$json_xs = $json_xs->ascii(0);
#$json_xs = $json_xs->allow_unknown(1);

my ($file) = @ARGV;
unless( defined $file && -f $file )
{
  print STDERR "usage: $0 FILE\n";
  exit 1;
}


my @cmd = ( qw( CMD ARGS ), $file );
open my $JSON, '-|', @cmd or die "Failed to exec @cmd: $!";

# local $/ = \4096; #read 4k at a time
while( my $line = <$JSON> )
{
  if( my $obj = json($line) )
  {
     print Dumper($obj);
  }
  else
  {
     die "error: failed to parse line - $line";
  }
  exit if( $. == 5 );
}

exit 0;

sub json
{
  my ($data) = @_;

  return decode_json($data);
}

sub json_parse
{
  my ($data) = @_;

  return json_to_perl($data);
}

sub json_xs
{
  my ($data) = @_;

  return $json_xs->decode($data);
}

sub json_xs_incremental
{
  my ($data) = @_;
  my $result = [];

  $json_xs->incr_parse($data);  # void context, so no parsing
  push( @$result, $_ ) for( $json_xs->incr_parse );

  return $result;
}

sub json_sl_incremental
{
  my ($data) = @_;
  my $result = [];

  $json_sl->feed($data);
  push( @$result, $_ ) for( $json_sl->fetch );
  # ? error: JSON::SL - Got error CANT_INSERT at position 552 at json_to_perl.pl line 82, <$JSON> line 2.

  return $result;
}
```