# How to Read Large files without consuming memory and fast in python

Tags: python, bigdata

I am having a file sized **15-16 GB**  containing **\n** separated JSON data (Approx 70-80 mil Data).

What will be the easiest way to read such large file in python without consuming much memory and also fast.

Also while reading such large file,If the script fails in between how to resume the reading from last read line using python?

Comment: "What will be the best programming language to read such huge file?" I'm assuming both languages have libraries for parsing JSON streams, so use whichever language you're most comfortable with. If that's Perl, see [How can I stream JSON from a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12460058/176646)

Comment: "Fast" is relative. Start with `for line in sys.stdin: process_data(json.loads(line))` and wrap with try/except, to skip lines that cause errors.

Comment: ijson (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) is the way to handle streaming json in python.

Comment: @nephlm : my file is not proper json file. File contains JSON objects seperated by new line (\n) .So will ijson work?

Comment: @LijoAbraham: If each json object is on it's own line (e.g. no new lines in the json objects than J.F. Sebastian's method will work.  I don't know if ijson will work on something that isn't a json stream.  You'd have to test it.