# How to read a https JSON stream with perl?

Tags: json, perl, https, lwp

Ok I'll try and be as detailed as possible.

I need to connect to a https url that streams JSON data, and search for keywords via REGEX as the data streams then take the matching JSON element decode it and insert it into a database.

The REGEX on is not the problem that's relatively simple.

What I'm struggling with is reading the data line wise. I've tried a few examples I found online the use LWP but where the stream never stops loading the script hangs.

Here's the closest I've gotten

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use IO::String;

my $handle = IO::String->new(get("https://stackoverflow.com"));
while (defined (my $line = <$handle>)) {
  print $line; #Inserted for testing

  #Decode and insert into DB here       
}
close $handle;
```

The data comes in a fairly fast rate so the script has to be efficient.

Any pointers as to how to get this done would be great.

Thanks
Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON::SL](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::SL) can help you.

Also see [Chas. Owens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12462153/257635) where he compares [JSON::SL](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::SL) and [JSON::Streaming::Reader](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::Streaming::Reader).

Comment: That helps a lot with processing the JSON still can't get my head around feeding the incoming data to JSON::SL.